# The top bar does not extend all the way on the profile page on iPad Pro (10.5in)

Tags: bug, profile-page, top-bar, design

On Safari running on an iPad Pro (10.5 inch) running iOS 11.2.5, the profile page looks like this:

[image]

The top bar does not go all the way to the right edge. I have indicated the white space left behind with a freehand circle.

Interestingly, this only happens on the profile page. I am guessing that's because the profile page's content is a bit wider than the rest of SO? I am not an expert in HTML/CSS.

Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: It does the same on my iPhone 8 plus, in Chrome for iOS. I assumed it was a minor downside of holding a ♦️.

Comment: *Is this a bug or by design?*, :D, let's hope a bug...

Comment: Clearly - white bug on white ground - taking the space.... you circled it quite nicely now it is fenced in and can not escape.

Comment: I can't reproduce on the 9.7 inch 2018 iPad. That may be because of a different screen size, or it could be because I'm on iOS 12.1.4.

Comment: Can't repro on iPhone 7, iOS 12.1.4, after requesting the desktop site (both portrait and landscape phone orientation).